# css cannot be recognized in github page

Tags: github-pages

my repo is https://github.com/dxcqcv/dxcqcv.github.io

js is work, but css cannot be recognized, I do not know why.

and I also google for 3 hours, no result for my case, css url is as the same base url as js url, why only css cannot be recognized?

you can visit my site https://dxcqcv.github.io, you can press F12 to  see console show `js works`, and you will be pleasantly surprised there are not css resources in network and resources. why???

please help, thank you~

Comment: Your `rel="stylesheets"` is wrong. `rel="stylesheet"` is what you want.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, my fault. and do you have some tools can easy find typo error like this, thx again~ –

Comment: Most IDEs offer auto-completion for stuff like `<link>` tags.

Comment: I used pug(jade), pug-lint and vscode IDE, but nothing hint, finally I found gulp-w3cjs works great, thx again.@ceejayoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typed an extra 's'.

Change this line:

```
<link href="/dxcqcv.github.io/css/index.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css">
```

To this line:

```
<link href="/dxcqcv.github.io/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: thanks, my fault. and do you have some tools can easy find typo error like this, thx again~